# Building Google Calendar Service Object w/ Service Account

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

As much as I'm looking through documentation from Google, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to build a service object that will allow me to manage my Google Calendar through a service account. Here's my code:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service_account_credentials.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

CAL = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

EVENT = {
    'summary': 'TEST EVENT',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': '2018-10-24T01:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Denver'
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': '2018-10-24T02:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Denver'
    }
}

CAL.event().insert(calendarId='primary', body=EVENT).execute()
```

When I run this code, I'm thrown this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 55, in <module>
    CAL.event().insert(calendarId=TEST_CALENDAR, body=EVENT).execute()
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'event'
```

When I create the CAL object, it's creating this kind of object: `<googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object at 0x00000249A24BB978>`, but I'm suppose to build some other object that has an `events().insert()` method that I can then use to post events to my Google Calendar.

Any idea on how to do that? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your script is almost the correct. But it is required to do a bit modification. So how about this modification?

#### From:

```
CAL.event().insert(calendarId='primary', body=EVENT).execute()
```

#### To:

```
CAL.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=EVENT).execute()
```

#### Note:

- In your script, it uses the service account. In this case, the calendar of `primary` means the owner of calendar is the service account.
- When the events are inserted to `primary` by the service account, it is inserted to the calendar of the service account. - If you want to insert events to the existing calendars which is not for the service account, please add the email of service account to the calendar as one of the shared users.

  - If you want to insert events to your calendar using the service account, please add the email of service account to your calendar as one of shared users. Then, please modify the calendar ID (in this case, it's not `primary`.) and run the script.

#### Reference:

- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Wow. Way to go me for missing that. Thank you so much-- it worked!

Comment: @Matt Youngberg I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.