# Having issues using "create_delegated" in oAuth Google Api Flow....gDrive

Tags: api, google-api, google-drive-api

Crux of the issue is when running the below I'm unable to delegate the crredentials to work in other users account. The only online examples are using a JSON service account and NOT an oAuth authentication flow.

```
newcreds = creds.create_delegated('__testusersearch__@gdev.bc.edu')
AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'create_delegated'
```

Highlights of my code are below where the normal credential login works great but need access to other users accounts.....

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

import sys

print('test')
##VARS
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']
creds = None
count = 0
##Google Creds
creds = None
if os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/secrets/token.pickle'):
    with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/secrets/token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/secrets/credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/secrets/token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

newcreds = creds.create_delegated('__testusersearch__@address.domain')

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question right. If you want to work in another user's account (so impersonate a user) - you need to use a service account rather than using the normal authentication flow (which would require the other user to sign in and type in his password).. What is wrong with using a JSON service account? It does not impede you to create `delegated_credentials` and act on the other user's behalf.

Comment: I'm a super admin though...once i'm in I should be able to delegate as the other use...

I was askiing why can't II with a standard oAuth account...i'm not sure iif i'm going about it incorrectly or that this isn't a feature iwth oAuth credentials..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manage users with Google-OAuth 2.0

Managing GSuite domain users has to be divided in two parts

1. [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk) methods such as creating users, retrieving users, updating users etc. (basically everything an admin can perform from within the [admin console](https://admin.google.com/))are accessible by the domain admin directly when authenticating with his credentials
2. Methods that involve the usage of most other APIs (Drive API, Gmail API etc.) and access to private user's data is not something a GSuite admin has direct access to.

For security reasons the latter must be performed through a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).

- When creating (or updating) a service account, the admin can decide which scopes to award to it and - perform [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation).
- Domain-wide delegation means that the service-account is allowed to represent a domain user by [impersonating](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) him - that is act as the user and get very much the same access to the users data as the user would himself.
- The authentication flow for working with service accounts is different from the common Google API authentication.
- There is no access or refresh token created in the same way and no `token.json` file is stored in the admin's working directory.
- Instead, when creating the service account in the GCP console, the service account credentials need to be downloaded as a `json` or `p12` file to the working directory.
- For using an impersonated service account with a `json` credentials file in Python define:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@example.org')
drive_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        'drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)
```

**`with_subject` is the crucial part to make the service impersonate a user.**

The indicated scopes must match the ones you assigned to the service account in your Admin console.

When using a service account, drop the code part for the normal authentication, that is

```
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

**Additional information**

If you prefer to use a `p12` credentials file instead of `json`, `with_subject` will be replaced through `create_delegated`.

Sample:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Email of the Service Account
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL'

# Path to the Service Account's Private Key file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = '/path/to/<public_key_fingerprint>-privatekey.p12'

def create_directory_service(user_email):
    """Build and returns an Admin SDK Directory service object authorized with the service accounts
    that act on behalf of the given user.

    Args:
      user_email: The email of the user. Needs permissions to access the Admin APIs.
    Returns:
      Admin SDK directory service object.
    """

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH,
        'notasecret',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)

    return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the posting and notes.

I needed to add entries into a public google calendar. Using guide: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert

I found that to do this effectively, I needed to use a service account: see: [Building Google Calendar Service Object w/ Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52976510/building-google-calendar-service-object-w-service-account)

I could not get the json credentials to work 100%. i.e. I could create a calendar entry but could not add any attendees. (Throws errors: "forbiddenForServiceAccounts", "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.")

I was only able to get the process working using a p12 credentials file. (see above)

I was able to manage Calendar entries in a free Google account using a registered service account.

Basic auth setup Needed:

1. setup G Suite for your private domain (https://support.google.com/a/answer/6365252). e.g. privatedomain.com
2. use the admin console to setup two paid google accounts: Admin (admin@privatedomain.com) and Utility (utility@privatedomain.com). Note you could do this with just the Admin account, but I was concerned about too much visibility to the Admin account.
3. create a project and service account. use the Service accounts page. I added roles: Owner & Service Account Token Creator
4. perform domain-wide delegation (https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation), and download the P12 key token file. Grant the service account the needed scopes. I gave the account too many scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar

Calendar setup Needed:

1. Make sure your calendar APP is allowed to share:
   a.  Google workspace and select calendar
   b.  Under General settings -> External sharing options for secondary calendars, allow “Share all information, and allow managing of calendars” and Save
2. In the user’s Google calendar APP, Create the needed calendar. Share the new calendar with your utility account (utility@privatedomain.com) with “Make changes and manage sharing” rights.
3. I suggest the following additional settings:

- Auto-accept invitations: Automatically add all…
- Make available to public: See all event details

4. Use the Integrate calendar -> Calendar ID in your code